# how to resolve OSGI dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, osgi

This is a very general kind of question. 
How can I resolve OSGI dependencies? I have a jar dependency which is not packaged as an OSGI bundle. Now if I want to use this jar do I need to explicitly create a bundle out of it? 
If so, how do I do it?

To be specific, I am trying to integrate wicket with some of the JQuery functionality using WIQuery. My wicket version is 1.4.17 and I am using Maven.

I want to use the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openengsb.forks</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.odlabs.wiquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.w1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried doing it by adding the above dependency in my pom and adding an import-package statement in configuration foeld of maven-bundle-plugin but kept getting missing constraint error on startup.

Comment: There's much missing from this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include in the manifest file of your OSGi bundle, and include the  WIQuery jar for OSGi in your OSGi environment.

With Maven, you should to include in the part of the code that write the manifest file. And then, you also need to add the jar of WIQuery in your OSGi container before you include your bundle.

If you look for this in Google, you [can see](https://code.google.com/p/wiquery/issues/detail?id=166) that there are work for integrate WIQuery and OSGi since 2011

Answer (score 0):

Look at these tutorials: http://web.ist.utl.pt/ist162500/?cat=2

You have to resolve your dependencies at compile time with the  tags and then you must provide the bundle at run time to your OSGi container.

> I've created this blog which explains in great detail how to cope with this OSGi issue: http://www.citizenrandom.com/?cat=2

Comment: Hey, dude. I can't see the content of your article...